# Octave's fzero() and Scipy's root() functions not producing the same result

Tags: python, scipy, octave

I have to find the zero of the following equation:

[image]

This is an equation of state, and it doesn't matter a whole lot if you don't know exactly what an EoS is. With the root of the above equation I compute (among other things) the compressibility factors of a gaseous substance, *Z*, for different pressures and temperatures. With those solutions I can plot families of curves having pressures as abscissas, *Z*s as ordinates and temperatures as parameters. Beta, delta, eta and phi are constants, as well as pr and Tr.

After banging my head unsuccessfully against the Newton-Raphson method (which works fine with several other EoSs) I decided to try Scipy's `root()` function. To my discontent, I obtained this chart:

[image]

As one can easily perceive, this saw-toothed chart is totally flawed. I should've gotten smooth curves instead. Also, *Z* typically ranges between 0.25 and 2.0. Thus, *Z*s equal to, say, 3 or above are completely off the mark. Yet the curves with *Z* < 2 look OK, although highly compressed because of the scale.

Then I tried Octave's `fzero()` solver, and got this:

[image]

Which is exactly what I should've gotten, as those are curves with the correct/expected shape!

Here comes my question. Apparently Scipy's `root()` and Octave's `fzero()` are based on the same algorithm *hybrid* from MINPACK. Still, the results clearly aren't the same. Do any of you know why?

I plotted a curve of the Zs obtained by Octave (abscissas) against the ones obtained with Scipy and got this:

[image]

The points at the bottom hinting a straight line represent `y = x`, i.e., the points for which Octave and Scipy agreed in the solutions they presented. The other points are in total disagreement and, unfortunately, they're too many to be simply ignored.

I might always use Octave from now on since it works, but I want to keep using Python.

What's your take on this? Any suggestion?

PS: Here's the original Python code. It produces the first chart shown here.

```
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import root
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fx(x, beta, delta, eta, phi, pr_, Tr_):
    tmp = phi*x**2
    etmp = numpy.exp(-tmp)
    f = x*(1.0 + beta*x + delta*x**4 + eta*x**2*(1.0 + tmp)*etmp) - pr_/Tr_
    return f

def zsbwr(pr_, Tr_, pc_, Tc_, zc_, w_, MW_, phase=0):

    d1 = 0.4912 + 0.6478*w_
    d2 = 0.3000 + 0.3619*w_
    e1 = 0.0841 + 0.1318*w_ + 0.0018*w_**2
    e2 = 0.075 + 0.2408*w_ - 0.014*w_**2
    e3 = -0.0065 + 0.1798*w_ - 0.0078*w_**2
    f = 0.770
    ee = (2.0 - 5.0*zc_)*numpy.exp(f)/(1.0 + f + 3.0*f**2 - 2*f**3)
    d = (1.0 - 2.0*zc_ - ee*(1.0 + f - 2.0*f**2)*numpy.exp(-f))/3.0
    b = zc_ - 1.0 - d - ee*(1.0 + f)*numpy.exp(-f)
    bc = b*zc_
    dc = d*zc_**4
    ec = ee*zc_**2
    phi = f*zc_**2
    beta = bc + 0.422*(1.0 - 1.0/Tr_**1.6) + 0.234*w_*(1.0- 1.0/Tr_**3)
    delta = dc*(1.0+ d1*(1.0/Tr_ - 1.0) + d2*(1.0/Tr_ - 1.0)**2)
    eta = ec + e1*(1.0/Tr_ - 1.0) + e2*(1.0/Tr_ - 1.0)**2 \
          + e3*(1.0/Tr_ - 1.0)**3

    if Tr_ > 1:
        y0 = pr_/Tr_/(1.0 + beta*pr_/Tr_)
    else:
        if phase == 0:
            y0 = pr_/Tr_/(1.0 + beta*pr_/Tr_)
        else:
            y0 = 1.0/zc_**(1.0 + (1.0 - Tr_)**(2.0/7.0))

    raiz = root(fx,y0,args=(beta, delta, eta, phi, pr_, Tr_),method='hybr',tol=1.0e-06)

    return pr_/raiz.x[0]/Tr_


if __name__ == "__main__":

    Tc = 304.13
    pc = 73.773
    omega = 0.22394
    zc = 0.2746
    MW = 44.01

    Tr = numpy.array([0.8, 0.93793103])
    pr = numpy.linspace(0.5, 14.5, 25)

    zfactor = numpy.zeros((2, 25))

    for redT in Tr:
        j = numpy.where(Tr == redT)[0][0]
        for redp in pr:
            indp = numpy.where(pr == redp)[0][0]
            zfactor[j][indp] = zsbwr(redp, redT, pc, Tc, zc, omega, MW, 0)

    for key, value in enumerate(zfactor):
        plt.plot(pr, value, '.-', linewidth=1, color='#ef082a')

    plt.figure(1, figsize=(7, 6))
    plt.xlabel('$p_R$', fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel('$Z$', fontsize=16)
    plt.grid(color='#aaaaaa', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
    plt.show()
```

And now the Octave script:

```
function SoaveBenedictWebbRubin

    format long;

    nTr = 11;
    npr = 43;

    ic = 1;

    nome = {"CO2"; "N2"; "H2O"; "CH4"; "C2H6"; "C3H8"};

    comp = [304.13, 73.773, 0.22394, 0.2746, 44.0100; ...
            126.19, 33.958, 0.03700, 0.2894, 28.0134; ...
            647.14, 220.640, 0.34430, 0.2294, 18.0153; ...
            190.56, 45.992, 0.01100, 0.2863, 16.0430; ...
            305.33, 48.718, 0.09930, 0.2776, 30.0700; ...
            369.83, 42.477, 0.15240, 0.2769, 44.0970];

    Tc = comp(ic,1);
    pc = comp(ic,2);
    w = comp(ic,3);
    zc = comp(ic,4);
    MW = comp(ic,5);

    Tr = linspace(0.8, 2.8, nTr);
    pr = linspace(0.2, 7.2, npr);

    figure(1, 'position',[300,150,600,500])

    for i=1:size(Tr, 2)
        icont = 1;
        zval = zeros(1, npr);
        for j=1:size(pr, 2)
            [Z, phi, density] = SBWR(Tr(i), pr(j), Tc, pc, zc, w, MW, 0);
            zval(icont) = Z;
            icont = icont + 1;
        endfor
        plot(pr,zval,'o','markerfacecolor','white','linestyle','-','markersize',3);
        hold on;
    endfor

    str = strcat("Soave-Benedict-Webb-Rubin para","\t",nome(ic));
    xlabel("p_r",'fontsize',15);
    ylabel("Z",'fontsize',15);
    title(str,'fontsize',12);
end

function [Z,phi,density] = SBWR(Tr, pr, Tc, pc, Zc, w, MW, phase)
    R = 8.3144E-5; % universal gas constant (bar·m3/(mol·K))

    % Definition of parameters
    d1 = 0.4912 + 0.6478*w;
    d2 = 0.3 + 0.3619*w;
    e1 = 0.0841 + 0.1318*w + 0.0018*w**2;
    e2 = 0.075 + 0.2408*w - 0.014*w**2;
    e3 = -0.0065 + 0.1798*w - 0.0078*w**2;
    f = 0.77;
    ee = (2.0 - 5.0*Zc)*exp(f)/(1.0 + f + 3.0*f**2 - 2.0*f**3);
    d = (1.0 - 2.0*Zc - ee*(1.0 + f - 2.0*f**2)*exp(-f))/3.0;
    b = Zc - 1.0 - d - ee*(1.0 + f)*exp(-f);
    bc = b*Zc;
    dc = d*Zc**4;
    ec = ee*Zc**2;
    ff = f*Zc**2;
    beta = bc + 0.422*(1.0 - 1.0/Tr**1.6) + 0.234*w*(1.0 - 1.0/Tr**3);
    delta = dc*(1.0 + d1*(1.0/Tr - 1.0) + d2*(1.0/Tr - 1.0)**2);
    eta = ec + e1*(1.0/Tr - 1.0) + e2*(1.0/Tr - 1.0)**2 + e3*(1.0/Tr - 1.0)**3;

    if Tr > 1
        y0 = pr/Tr/(1.0 + beta*pr/Tr);
    else
        if phase == 0
            y0 = pr/Tr/(1.0 + beta*pr/Tr);
        else
            y0 = 1.0/Zc**(1.0 + (1.0 - Tr)**(2.0/7.0));
        end
    end

    fun = @(y)y*(1.0 + beta*y + delta*y**4 + eta*y**2*(1.0 + ff*y**2)*exp(-ff*y**2)) - pr/Tr;

    options = optimset('TolX',1.0e-06);
    yi = fzero(fun,y0,options);

    Z = pr/yi/Tr;
    density = yi*pc*MW/(1000.0*R*Tc);
    phi = exp(Z - 1.0 - log(Z) + beta*yi + 0.25*delta*yi**4 - eta/ff*(exp(-ff*yi**2)*(1.0 + 0.5*ff*yi**2) - 1.0));
end
```

Comment: Show us the python code. There are likely several roots to converge to

Comment: @ev-br Done. Hopefully it will work for you. Let me know otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: @ev-br There are certainly multiple roots. What amazes me is that Octave finds the correct one(s) from the supplied initial guess. And the method is (quite likely) the same used by ```scipy.optimize.root()```.

Comment: @ev-br Also, the ```phi``` the function ```zsbwr()``` returns is _not_ the Greek letter phi shown in the equation for f(x) up above. This latter should be ```ff```. I made my code a bit confused. Sorry for that.

Comment: would you mind also sharing the octave code?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, Done.

Comment: I note that your parameters (pr and Tr) are different in the two versions. Perhaps that is an issue?  (I also don't spot the universal gas constant anywhere in the python code, but you're not plotting the variables involved there, so I don't think this is related)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, I found out (see below) that the problems in finding the correct zeros arise when Tr = 0.8 or Tr = 0.93793103. In fact, Tr = 0.9 also yields incorrect roots, hinting that the root-finding method in SciPy does not work for Tr < 1. Still, Octave handles those roots quite well, and that's the essence of the question I asked: why does Octave work so well where SciPy fails so badly? A bug? I though of writing to SciPy's mailing list, but was suggested to try Stackoverflow first (more readers, more resources and so on).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou do you mean the underscore in Tr_ which does not appear in Octave's version? No, that's not an issue. The underscore was just a way to stop the Python IDE from complaining about "repeated variables" which in the present case is a silly concern. Results will be the same if you remove the underscores from pr_ and Tr_. As for the universal constant of the gases, I placed it there just in case, but as it turns out is not necessary. You can remove it without causing any jeopardy to the code.

Comment: No I mean the two versions are not equivalent. The octave version uses different values for Tr and Pr than the python version. (your pr linspace is different for instance)

Comment: Sorry for the different linspaces, I hadn't noticed that. Someone asked me to "trim" the code to a minimum emphasizing the parameters causing problems, what I did, thus the codes you see above are not the original ones I started with and showed earlier (before the trimming &c). Therefore, the Python code you see above plots two curves only, for Tr = 0.8 and 0.93793103, which are the values which cause trouble. As I wrote above, root() fails in determining the roots for Tr < 1, for reasons still unknown to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. Your two files weren't equivalent, therefore a direct comparison of the underlying algorithms was difficult. I attach here an octave and a python version that are directly comparable line-for-line that can be compared side-by-side.

```matlab
%%% File: SoaveBenedictWebbRubin.m:
% No package imports necessary

function SoaveBenedictWebbRubin()

    nome = {"CO2"; "N2"; "H2O"; "CH4"; "C2H6"; "C3H8"};
    comp = [ 304.13,  73.773,  0.22394,  0.2746,  44.0100;
             126.19,  33.958,  0.03700,  0.2894,  28.0134;
             647.14, 220.640,  0.34430,  0.2294,  18.0153;
             190.56,  45.992,  0.01100,  0.2863,  16.0430;
             305.33,  48.718,  0.09930,  0.2776,  30.0700;
             369.83,  42.477,  0.15240,  0.2769,  44.0970  ];

    nTr = 11;   Tr = linspace( 0.8, 2.8, nTr );
    npr = 43;   pr = linspace( 0.2, 7.2, npr );
    ic  = 1;
    Tc  = comp(ic, 1);
    pc  = comp(ic, 2);
    w   = comp(ic, 3);
    zc  = comp(ic, 4);
    MW  = comp(ic, 5);

    figure(1, 'position',[300,150,600,500])

    zvalues = zeros( nTr, npr );
    
    for i = 1 : nTr
        for j = 1 : npr
            zvalues(i,j) = zSBWR( Tr(i), pr(j), Tc, pc, zc, w, MW, 0 );
        endfor
    endfor

    hold on
    for i = 1 : nTr
        plot( pr, zvalues(i,:), 'o-', 'markerfacecolor', 'white', 'markersize', 3);
    endfor
    hold off

    xlabel( "p_r", 'fontsize', 15 );
    ylabel( "Z"  , 'fontsize', 15 );
    title( ["Soave-Benedict-Webb-Rubin para\t", nome(ic)], 'fontsize', 12 );

endfunction % main



function Z = zSBWR( Tr, pr, Tc, pc, Zc, w, MW, phase )

  % Definition of parameters
    d1 =  0.4912 + 0.6478 * w;
    d2 =  0.3    + 0.3619 * w;
    e1 =  0.0841 + 0.1318 * w + 0.0018 * w ** 2;
    e2 =  0.075  + 0.2408 * w - 0.014  * w ** 2;
    e3 = -0.0065 + 0.1798 * w - 0.0078 * w ** 2;
    f  =  0.77;
    ee = (2.0 - 5.0 * Zc) * exp( f ) / (1.0 + f + 3.0 * f ** 2 - 2.0 * f ** 3 );
    d  = (1.0 - 2.0 * Zc  - ee * (1.0 + f - 2.0 * f ** 2) * exp( -f ) ) / 3.0;
    b  = Zc - 1.0 - d - ee * (1.0 + f) * exp( -f );
    bc = b  * Zc;
    dc = d  * Zc ** 4;
    ec = ee * Zc ** 2;
    phi = f  * Zc ** 2;
    beta  = bc + 0.422 * (1.0 - 1.0 / Tr ** 1.6) + 0.234 * w * (1.0 - 1.0 / Tr ** 3);
    delta = dc * (1.0 + d1 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) + d2 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) ** 2);
    eta   = ec + e1 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) + e2 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) ** 2 + e3 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) ** 3;


    if Tr > 1
        y0 = pr / Tr / (1.0 + beta * pr / Tr);
    else
        if phase == 0
            y0 = pr / Tr / (1.0 + beta * pr / Tr);
        else
            y0 = 1.0 / Zc ** (1.0 + (1.0 - Tr) ** (2.0 / 7.0) );
        endif
    endif


    yi = fzero( @(y) fx(y, beta, delta, eta, phi, pr, Tr), y0, optimset( 'TolX', 1.0e-06 ) );
    Z = pr / yi / Tr;

endfunction % zSBWR




function Out = fx( y, beta, delta, eta, phi, pr, Tr )
    Out = y * (1.0 + beta * y + delta * y ** 4 + eta * y ** 2 * (1.0 + phi * y ** 2) * exp( -phi * y ** 2 ) ) - pr / Tr;
endfunction
```

```python
### File: SoaveBenedictWebbRubin.py
import numpy;   from scipy.optimize import root;   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def SoaveBenedictWebbRubin():

    nome = ["CO2", "N2", "H2O", "CH4", "C2H6", "C3H8"]
    comp = numpy.array( [ [ 304.13,  73.773,  0.22394,  0.2746,  44.0100 ],
                          [ 126.19,  33.958,  0.03700,  0.2894,  28.0134 ],
                          [ 647.14, 220.640,  0.34430,  0.2294,  18.0153 ],
                          [ 190.56,  45.992,  0.01100,  0.2863,  16.0430 ],
                          [ 305.33,  48.718,  0.09930,  0.2776,  30.0700 ],
                          [ 369.83,  42.477,  0.15240,  0.2769,  44.0970 ] ] )

    nTr = 11;   Tr = numpy.linspace( 0.8, 2.8, nTr )
    npr = 43;   pr = numpy.linspace( 0.2, 7.2, npr )
    ic  = 0
    Tc  = comp[ic, 0]
    pc  = comp[ic, 1]
    w   = comp[ic, 2]
    zc  = comp[ic, 3]
    MW  = comp[ic, 4]

    plt.figure(1, figsize=(7, 6))

    zvalues = numpy.zeros( (nTr, npr) )

    for i in range( nTr ):
        for j in range( npr ):
            zvalues[i,j] = zsbwr( Tr[i], pr[j], pc, Tc, zc, w, MW, 0)
        # endfor
    # endfor


    for i in range(nTr):
        plt.plot(pr, zvalues[i, :], 'o-', markerfacecolor='white', markersize=3 )



    plt.xlabel( '$p_r$', fontsize = 15 )
    plt.ylabel( '$Z$'  , fontsize = 15 )
    plt.title( "Soave-Benedict-Webb-Rubin para\t" + nome[ic], fontsize = 12 );
    plt.show()
# end function main



def zsbwr( Tr, pr, pc, Tc, zc, w, MW, phase=0):

  # Definition of parameters
    d1 =  0.4912 + 0.6478 * w
    d2 =  0.3000 + 0.3619 * w
    e1 =  0.0841 + 0.1318 * w + 0.0018 * w ** 2
    e2 =  0.075  + 0.2408 * w - 0.014  * w ** 2
    e3 = -0.0065 + 0.1798 * w - 0.0078 * w ** 2
    f  = 0.770
    ee = (2.0 - 5.0 * zc) * numpy.exp( f ) / (1.0 + f + 3.0 * f ** 2 - 2 * f ** 3)
    d  = (1.0 - 2.0 * zc - ee * (1.0 + f - 2.0 * f ** 2) * numpy.exp( -f )) / 3.0
    b  = zc - 1.0 - d - ee * (1.0 + f) * numpy.exp( -f )
    bc = b * zc
    dc = d * zc ** 4
    ec = ee * zc ** 2
    phi = f * zc ** 2
    beta  = bc + 0.422 * (1.0 - 1.0 / Tr ** 1.6) + 0.234 * w * (1.0 - 1.0 / Tr ** 3)
    delta = dc * (1.0 + d1 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) + d2 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) ** 2)
    eta   = ec + e1 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) + e2 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) ** 2 + e3 * (1.0 / Tr - 1.0) ** 3


    if Tr > 1:
        y0 = pr / Tr / (1.0 + beta * pr / Tr)
    else:
        if phase == 0:
            y0 = pr / Tr / (1.0 + beta * pr / Tr)
        else:
            y0 = 1.0 / zc ** (1.0 + (1.0 - Tr) ** (2.0 / 7.0))
        # endif
    # endif


    yi = root( fx, y0, args = (beta, delta, eta, phi, pr, Tr), method = 'hybr', tol = 1.0e-06 ).x
    return pr / yi / Tr

# endfunction zsbwr




def fx(y, beta, delta, eta, phi, pr, Tr):
    return y*(1.0 + beta*y + delta*y**4 + eta*y**2*(1.0 + phi*y**2)*numpy.exp(-phi*y**2)) - pr/Tr
# endfunction fx




if __name__ == "__main__":   SoaveBenedictWebbRubin()
```

This confirms that the outputs from the two systems do in fact differ partly due to the outputs of the underlying algorithms used, rather than because the programs weren't the effectively the same. However, the comparison is not as bad now:

[image]
[image]

As for "the algorithms are the same", they are not. Octave typically hides more technical implementation details in the source code, so this is always worth checking. In particular, in file fzero.m, right after the docstring, it mentions the following:

> This is essentially the [ACM "Algorithm 748: Enclosing Zeros of Continuous Functions" due to Alefeld, Potra and Shi, ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, Vol. 21, No. 3, September 1995](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/210089.210111).
>
> Although the workflow should be the same, the structure of the algorithm has been transformed non-trivially; instead of the authors' approach of sequentially calling building blocks subprograms we implement here a FSM version using one interior point determination and one bracketing per iteration, thus reducing the number of temporary variables and simplifying the algorithm structure.  Further, this approach reduces the need for external functions and error handling. The algorithm has also been slightly modified.

Whereas according to `help(root)`:

> **Notes**
> This section describes the available solvers that can be selected by the 'method' parameter. The default method is *hybr*.
>
> Method *hybr* uses a modification of the Powell hybrid method as
> implemented in MINPACK [1].

> **References**
> [1] [More, Jorge J., Burton S. Garbow, and Kenneth E. Hillstrom. 1980. User Guide for MINPACK-1.](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/6997568)

I tried a couple of the alternatives mentioned in `help(root)`. The `df-sane` one seems to be optimised for 'scalar' values (i.e. like 'fzero'). Indeed, while not as good as octave's implementation, this does give a slightly 'saner' (pun intended) result:

[image]

Having said all that, the hybrid method doesn't dump any warnings, but if you use some of the other alternatives, many of them will inform you that you have a lot of effective divisions by zero, nans, and infs, in places were you shouldn't, which is presumably why you get such weird results. So, perhaps it's not that octave's algorithm is "better" per se, but that it handles "division by zero" instances in this problem slightly more gracefully.

I don't know the exact nature of your problem, but it may be that the algorithms on python's side simply expect you to feed it well-conditioned problems instead. Perhaps some of your computations in zsbwr() result in division by zero occasions or unrealistic zeros etc, which you could detect and treat as special cases?

Comment: First off, many thanks for your detailed & kind reply. Indeed, your 2nd chart looks much better than mine, although the blue curve is totally ballistic and shows a unrealistic behaviour (typically, I wouldn't expect a Z>=2, although this is a theoretically possible value). I bet this blue curve is the one for Tr = 0.8. And I don't think (but cannot prove) that this has to do with numerical exceptions & with Octave handling them more gracefully as you said. IMO this is an implementation flaw because the returned values, although abnormally high, aren't as crazy as, say, O(10**10) or something.

Comment: (Continued) Therefore, Z = 7 is weird, and yet it looks (to the untrained eye) an educated root. I think we will never find a definitive answer to this puzzle. What I can do is to always keep an eye on solutions like this one when another opportunity to solve a complex equation like that comes. This was a complicated one. The EOSs I have opportunity to study and use are much simpler than this SBWR one. Again, many thanks for your answer; I would upvote it twice if I could. ;-)

Comment: @CarlosGouveia well, you can accept the answer if you think it answers your question :p   (I suppose it answers the "aren't they the same algorithm" part, to which the answer is basically 'no'). As for whether the graphs make sense, I suppose the reasonable thing to do (if you haven't already) is to simply plot the EOS equation over the domain of `x` for various values of `pr` (and a fixed `Tr`, e.g. the one you think is the problematic one), and see if the plots you get make sense or visually explain why the 'root-finding' algorithms have trouble finding the zeros in that scenario!

Comment: Do I have to "officially" accept an answer? Like, to close this topic? How do I do that? I would gladly accept your answer, Tasos.

Comment: @CarlosGouveia you don't "have to" accept an answer if none of the answers are suitable, but if an answer answers your question then it is good to do so, primarily so that the question appears closed in the list of questions, which then helps other people googling with a similar question. You "accept" an answer by clicking on the 'tick' next to the answer (just below the voting arrows). Note that accepting an answer doesn't "close" a topic in that sense. You are free to change your mind at any time and choose another answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Please trim the code to a minimum example which only show the root-finding part and parameters where it finds an unwanted root.)

Then the procedure is to manually inspect the equation to find the localization interval for the root you want and use it. I typically use `brentq`.

Comment: Done. I trimmed it the maximum I could. I also found out that the problem happens when Tr = 0.8 and Tr = 0.93793103, thus the trimmed code now plots a chart for those two reduced temperatures only. SciPy, for some unfathomable reason, doesn't come along well with those two Trs. Octave, however, handles them quite nicely.